# Como retornar o resultado esperado nessa query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

Boa tarde pessoal. O caso é o seguinte: eu tenho uma tabela com 2 blogs de categoria "automovel" e parte do título "Hackers" então qualquer que seja minha query, não pode retornar mais do que dois resultados combinando o "titulo" e a "categoria". Me ajudem a resolver esta query para obter o resultado desejado?

Atualmente ela está encontrando 5 resultados, o que quer dizer que a query está puxando os blogs da categoria "alimentacao" ignorando a combinação com o título.

```
    $result = $this->db->query("
                               SELECT * FROM blogs AS bl
                               INNER JOIN blog_categoria AS blc
                               ON bl.bc_id = blc.id
                               WHERE bl.bl_title
                               LIKE '%Hackers%'
                               AND blc.bc_urllink = 'automoveis'
                               OR blc.bc_urllink = 'alimentacao'
                               ");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sua condição atual pode ser dividida nessas duas partes:

> 1: Hacker **E** Automóveis
>        **OU**
>     2: Alimentos

Na verdade, o que você quer é isto:

> 1: Hacker
>     **E**
>     2: Automóveis **OU** Alimentos

Assim, precisa por parênteses no segundo grupo para que eles sejam resolvidos como uma condição só, ficando assim:

```
$result = $this->db->query("
                           SELECT * FROM blogs AS bl
                           INNER JOIN blog_categoria AS blc
                           ON bl.bc_id = blc.id
                           WHERE bl.bl_title
                           LIKE '%Hackers%'
                           AND ( blc.bc_urllink = 'automoveis'
                           OR blc.bc_urllink = 'alimentacao' )
                           ");
```

Comment: Waouuuuwwww e eu pensei que eu estava péssimo em programação. rsrsrs Obrigado Bacco